# Forcing IE to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: java, c#, internet-explorer, https, proxy-server

I am relatively new here and I hope this question meet the standards set here.

My university has blocked access to the internet and the only way to access it is through a proxy server.

I downloaded 1 such program from here.
http://www.nsftools.com/tips/jProxy.java

But here the author has mentioned that HTTPS doesnt work with CONNECT requests. Now currently I am using Firefox and **this** technique to disable HTTPS forwarding.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959914

Currently I am developing my own browser in C#. I know C# web-browser class is a subset of IE. And whenever I give request in

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com")
```

It forwards the page to

```
https://www.google.co.in/
```

. Are there any settings in IE like Firefox or C# to send just the HTTP request?

(Note: I know HTTPS is more secure but I need HTTP. If anyone can tell me a workaround for this Proxyserver to work with HTTPS link also, its very appreciated)
Thanks in advance for your time, suggestions and answers.

Comment: google is accessible through HTTPS only

Comment: It can also be accessed through HTTP. Please refer the links I've shown

Comment: Browser does not make a decision how server serves content (also since "I am developing my own browser" you already know that), so you really need proxy that will connect to servers via HTTPS and return you everything as HTTP... and it need to be smart to properly rewrite pages/scripts/CSS to update all links to HTTP (but again you should know that too by now)... As result the question see to be "what proxy I should use" which is off-topic as tools reco.